# Separate number from text

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am using excel 2010 and I am having the following text in one cell:

```
Hash Rates
44Th/s
485Mh/s
432Mh/s
7Th/s
365Mh/s
33Th/s
3.1Th/s
6Th/s
10Gh/s
240kh/s
24.5Th/s
160kh/s
```

I would like to separate the number from the text. For example for `44Th/s`, I would like to get `44` and `Th/s`.

I tried creating a helper cell go get the position of the number and text with the following formula:

```
=MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};E2&"0123456789"))
```

As a result I am now trying to separate the text from the number with:

```
=RIGHT(E2;LEN(E2)-L2+1)
```

However, I only get the initial text back:

```
Hash Rates
44Th/s
485Mh/s
432Mh/s
```

Any suggestions how to separate text from number?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634174/formula-to-extract-numbers-from-a-text-string

Comment: @FrankBall none of those suggestions would work - all are Google Spreadsheet-related, except for the `TEXTJOIN` solution, which wouldn't work in Excel 2010

Comment: Do you have a list of "rates", e.g. `Th/s`, `Mh/s`, etc?

Comment: I recommend power query in excel for this here is a example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210897/excel-how-to-split-cells-by-comma-delimiter-into-new-cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the numbers:

```
=LEFT(A2,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2))),1))),1))
```

Then this to get the text:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`=MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};E2&"0123456789"))` returns 1, because that all your data starts with a number.

Try this instead:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(E2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(E2)));1)={"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"."}))`

This can be combined with your formula, so that goes to:

**Number Part:**

`=--LEFT(E2;SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(E2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(E2)));1)={"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"."})))`

**Text Part**

`=RIGHT(E2;LEN(E2)-SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(E2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(E2)));1)={"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"."})))`

Comment: I don't thing your sumproduct is working.  as far as I understand the arrays, length of number and the numbers must be the same length. I get #REF! errors.

Comment: Maybe it's due to the difference of `;` and `,`

Comment: Yes when making the array horizontal with `,` it works but vertical with `;` does not work.

Comment: I just changed all `,` into `;` in my formula to fit in OP's language setting. Not sure about how the array in OP's computer looks.

Comment: I too am not sure what the delimiter is for a horizontal array when `;` is the standard delimiter for the formula.