# REGEXEXTRACT multiple values - Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I have the following entries in ONE google sheets cell

```
12@xy.de; 123@xy.de; 1234@xy.de; ext!abc@def.de!; 321@xy.de; ext!def@abc.de!; 4321@xy.de;
```

Now I would like to create the following output (in one cell aswell) using formulas.

Expected Result:

```
abc@def.de; def@abc.de
```

I tried using `REGEXEXTRACT` but this function only return the first
match (abc@def.de)

Any proposals?

Comment: Does this mean you want all addresses inside `ext!...!`, or all that consist only of letters for the identifiers, or both? Please add a description of what matches you are looking for to your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432409/multiple-regex-matches-in-google-sheets-formula

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("; "; 1; IF(REGEXMATCH(
 SPLIT(A1; ";"); "abc@def.de|def@abc.de"); SPLIT(A1; ";"); ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks I like that approach. However I would prefer a dynamic solution. My real data has way more lines with that format (ext!y@aa.de!). Moreover people will frequently add new lines. So I dont want the specific lines to be "hard coded" in the formula. Is this even feasible?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with fake data and example of desired output?

Comment: @DocBenchpress can you modify your question in this case? So that it would not seem that this is a chameleon question

Comment: I would try to use this regex and modify as you wish `\w{2,3}\!\w{2,3}\@\w{2,3}\.\w{2,3}\!`, try it on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)