# Spreadsheet clean text and split by regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula

I have this string:

```
Engaged View Beacon Url: https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackimp/..., Dcm Beacon Url: https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackimp/.....
```

I try to extract the two urls from it.

I have tried this, but I get only the first url. Why? How can I improve this?

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(F21, "Dcm Beacon Url: ", "♥"), "Engaged View Beacon Url: ", ""), "♥")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the entire string, so we don't know what markers there are to work with. That said, you can try this (assuming your raw string were in A2):

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,REPT(".+(http[^\s,]+)",2))`

The output will require *two* horizontal cells. So if you place this in B2, make sure that both B2 and C2 are free first.

If that doesn't work, consider sharing the *entire* string you are trying to break.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISURL(SPLIT(A2, " ")), 
 SPLIT(A2, " "), )),,9^9)), " ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer and modification I saw from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432409/multiple-regex-matches-in-google-sheets-formula)

```
=transpose(split(join(",",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(https[^,]+)","($1)"))), ","))
```

[image]

You can opt to remove transpose, I just used it to show the result clearly.