# Extract strings in a pattern from within another regex pattern: REGEX (Replace, Extract $1)

Tags: regex, google-sheets

How can I extract strings in a pattern from within another regex pattern
Exemple:

```
REGEXREPLACE("Ex.: <a;b;c;> e <d;e;>.","<(.*?)>","($1)...")
```

to get

```
Ex: (a)(b)(c) e (d)(e).
```

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:

You can try a nested `REGEXREPLACE` functions then use `SUBSTITUTE` at the end like this sample below:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE
           (REGEXREPLACE
           (REGEXREPLACE
           ("<a;b;c;> e <d;e;>.", "<(.*?)>", "($1)"),
            "[^a-z()> .a-z]", ")*("),
            "[^a-z()> .a-z]",""),
           "()","")
```

### Sample Demonstration

> Sample string is on cell `A2`

[image]

### *How it works:*

1. Used your original regex:

> E.g. placed on cell `A2`

`=REGEXREPLACE("<a;b;c;> e <d;e;>.", "<(.*?)>", "($1)")`

> Result: `(a;b;c;) e (d;e;).`

2. Replace `;` with `)*(`:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "[^a-z()> .a-z]", ")*(")`

> Result: `(a)*(b)*(c)*() e (d)*(e)*().`

3. Remove asterisk **(*)** sign:

`=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"[^a-z()> .a-z]","")`

> Result: `(a)(b)(c)() e (d)(e)().`

4. Replace empty `()` using `[SUBSTITUTE][2]` function:

`=SUBSTITUTE(C2,"()","")`

> Result: `(a)(b)(c) e (d)(e).`

### Reference:

[Multiple regex matches in Google Sheets formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432409/multiple-regex-matches-in-google-sheets-formula)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the effort. But in your method any terms separated by ";" are enclosed in parentheses, (or characters other than "^a-z()> .a-z"), even if outside of "<>".

Comment: You're welcome. I see, if you'll have ";" outside of the "<>" on your actual string, then it looks like it's close to impossible/very tricky to disregard/remove any ";" from the outside. This is because the only way I can think of is by using `Lookahead`, see this [sample](https://regex101.com/r/5dnsPj/2). However, Google Sheet is using RE2 & `Lookahead` isn't supported. I tried several other methods but they don't work as well.

Comment: I got something cool, even using part of your reasoning sequence.

=SUBSTITUTE("This; is the new test; <a;b;c;> e <d;e;>." , ";" , "><")
=REGEXREPLACE(B11 , "<([^<]*?)>" , "($1)")
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B12 , "><" , ";") , "()" , )