# Google sheets regexextract multiple results

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a string `opposed to unit sales @d. Moving rev @i. Before used to down @test.`

I need to extract all of the text with @ tags before the period including the @.

The results should be: `@d @i @test`

I can match everything using `@([^\.]*)` but I read that since google sheet doesn't do multiple extract, i need to replace everything except my pattern with `" "` then split to get the results.

I'm having problems producing a formula that uses `regexreplace` for everything except my pattern.

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43432409)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following simple formula

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(C1,"(@\w+)|.", "$1 "))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)

Answer (score 3):

The commonly accepted way to do this is by using `REGEXREPLACE` to capture all the matches

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"@\w+","($0)")
```

And then using `REGEXEXTRACT` to extract them

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"@\w+","($0)"))
```

If the string contains regex special characters, we have to escape them first

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[()\[\]{}|\\^$.+*?]","\\$0"),"@\w+","($0)"))
```

Answer (score 3):

***`regex way`***:

```
=regexreplace(regexreplace(A2,"(@[^@\.]+)\.( )?|.","$1$2")," $",)
```

***`non-regex solution`***(*joined in single cell*):

```
=let(Σ,split(A2," "),textjoin(" ",1,index(if((left(Σ)="@")*(right(Σ)="."),substitute(Σ,".",),))))
```

***`non-regex solution`***(*split across cells*):

```
=let(Σ,split(A2," "),torow(index(if((left(Σ)="@")*(right(Σ)="."),substitute(Σ,".",),)),1))
```

[image]